# Is it correct to say "These terms are less using in nowadays"?

Tags: passive-voice, adverb-placement

I presented 4 groups of biological terms, while just 2 of them are used in nowadays, and the 2 other groups are less. So when I refer to the other 2 groups, can I say about them the following sentence? (For me it sounds a little weird and that's why I'm asking this question)

> "These terms are less using in nowadays"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> These terms are less using in nowadays.

This is not idiomatic English.

- *are using* is an active form of the verb *use*, and implies that the subject (*terms*, in this example) performs the action. What you want is the passive form: *BE* + past participle.

  > These terms are less ***used***
- *nowadays* is an adverb, not a noun, so it cannot stand as the object of a preposition like *in*. It means *in these days* all by itself.

  > These terms are less used ***nowadays***.
- Adverbs and short adverbial phrases of frequency (*often*, *very rarely*, *usually*) are usually placed where you have placed *less*, after the first auxiliary verb. But comparatives (*more*, *less*) are usually placed after the lexical (main) verb and its complements.

  > These terms are used ***less*** nowadays.
  >   People use these terms ***less*** nowadays.

  This is because *less* and *more* often introduce longer comparative constructions with *than* which would make the syntactic core harder to parse if placed in the ordinary position.

  > <sup>∗</sup> These terms are less than they were ten years ago used nowadays.
  >   <sup>ok</sup>These terms are used less nowadays than they were ten years ago.

Comment: Another alternative (which the OP may have been half-remembering) would be “These terms are **less in use** nowadays…”, which means roughly the same as “…used less…”.

Comment: It's not just unidiomatic; it's senseless!

Answer (score 5):

The passive participial construction is formed nowadays with **is|are|was|were being** plus the past participle

**...are being used...**

**Blood-letting *was being used* to lower fever as late as the mid-19th century. It was discredited in the late 19th century and *is not being used* nowadays.**

Comment: +1 for discreetly accommodating the old passival without confusing OP by actually mentioning it!

Comment: [**passival**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/passival) *- an **archaic** progressive construction in middle voice (syntactically active but semantically passive), replaced by the passive progressive in modern English. For example, "the house is building", "the meal was eating"*. But to my mind the "continuous" aspect is equally inappropriate today, ***and is not used nowadays***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly so. And in fact I doubt the passival was ever used with atelic verbs like *use*; there was really no need for a progressive passive where the sense was inherently imperfective.

Comment: @StoneyB: The whole thing is probably well beyond my pay grade. I'm not even clear as to whether [*this wine is drinking well*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+wine+is+drinking+well%22) is a "passival" usage or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, that's a kind of recategorization of *drink*, like *cook* or *drive* -- I just yesterday learned to call verbs that work like that *labile verbs*. The passival is *There's a house building on the corner*, which was standard for expressing progressive passive until the *BE being VERBen* construction appeared in the Coleridge/Southey circle in the 1790s. It took only two generations for the modern form to become firmly established (in the face of virulent opposition) and completely eliminate the old passival from Modern English.

Comment: @StoneyB: It just occurred to me that [*the house is **abuilding / a-building***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+house+is+abuilding%22) seemed to me to be primarily "archaic" because of the ***a / a-*** prefix, so I searched for it in Google Books. This is typical of the instances I found: *The history of the passival form is confused with that of the type **the house is abuilding,** descended from OE expressions with **on** followed by the verbal noun in **-unge.*** All that tells me is I'm *definitely* outside my pay grade here!

Answer (score 2):

For starters, it is *nowadays*, not ***in** nowadays*.

Then, you used the correct form of the verb *use* in your first sentence (two of them *are used* nowadays) so why change it in the other sentence?

Finally, it's more natural to move *less* after the verb. This way we end up with:

> These terms are used less nowadays.

Which is fine. If you want some variation, you can say:

> These terms are less in use nowadays.
>   These terms are (almost) out of use nowadays.